# Laravel : is it possible to pass a locale to Validator

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel controllers I validate requests like this:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate(UserValidator::$updateIfNeeded);
```

Now, is it possible to pass a locale string to a validator, like "es" or "en"?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. You can pass a locale string to the validator for validation like e.g. `->validate([ 'locale' => 'in:en,es' ])` for example but you can't pass a locale as a validator parameter to determine what validation messages to use (it uses the global locale for most things but is not fully localised)

Answer (score 0):

No need to do that, Laravel's built-in validation rules each has an error message that is located in your application's `lang/en/validation.php` file. Within this file, you will find a translation entry for each validation rule. You are free to change or modify these messages based on the needs of your application.

In addition, you may copy this file to another translation language directory to translate the messages for your application's language. To learn more about Laravel localization, check out the Laravel Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation

Answer (score 0):

If your locale set in your route, you can access to It with `request()->LocaleParameter`. If you set locale earlier than validator, you can access to it with `app()->getLocale()` or `Config::get('app.locale')`